# Google Sheets regexextract first letter of each word

Tags: regex, google-sheets, array-formulas, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

how do I display the first letter of each word in let's say cell A1:

Example:

> A1= Foo bar
>
> A1= Foo

in the first example, I want to display "Fb"

in the second example, I want to see "F"

If A1 = empty I don't want to show anything

I tried this:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1;"^.")
```

that shows only the first letter

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about this? Please think of this as just one of several answers.

#### Modified formula:

```
=IF(A1="","",JOIN("",ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXEXTRACT(SPLIT(A1," "),"\b[\w]"))))
```

1. When the cell "A1" is empty and not empty, `""` and the first letters of each word are put, respectively.
2. Split the value to each word using `SPLIT`.
3. Retrieve the first letter from each word using `REGEXEXTRACT` and `ARRAYFORMULA`.

   - Regular expression of `\b[\w]` was used.
4. Join each array using `JOIN`.

#### Result:

[image]

#### References:

- [SPLIT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136)
- [REGEXEXTRACT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244)
- [ARRAYFORMULA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)
- [JOIN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094077)

If this was not the result you want, I apologize.

### Added:

As an other, it uses `LEFT` instead of `REGEXEXTRACT`.

#### Modified formula:

```
=IF(A1="","",JOIN("",ARRAYFORMULA(LEFT(SPLIT(A1," ")))))
```

#### Reference:

- [LEFT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094079)

Comment: Yes, both works, I use the first example. I haven't used split and join before, I need to study that, its very handy. Tanks a bunch

Comment: @Ralph Schipper Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. When the value is splitted by ``SPLIT``, the value is an array. So I used ``ARRAYFORMULA``.

Answer (score 4):

the true array formula would be:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A1:A); 
 SUBSTITUTE(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(SPLIT(A1:A; " "); 
 "\b[\w]"))); ; 999^99)); " "; ); ))
```

[image: 0]